# Determine the unique string from a repeating string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-parsing

I need to develop an efficient algorithm for determining the unique (repeated) string given a string with repeating content (and only repeating content)...

For example:

`"AbcdAbcdAbcdAbcd"` => `"Abcd"`

`"Hello"` => `"Hello"`

I'm having some trouble coming up with an algorithm that is fairly efficient; any input would be appreciated.

Clarification: I want **the shortest string that, when repeated enough times, is equal to the total string**.

Comment: Wouldn't "AbcdAbcdAbcdAbcd" be also a result for the first example, given how it was handled in the second one?

Comment: @SystemDown No, because the string repeats. The string will contain *only* repeating text. So, the second example repeated one time.

Comment: `"555"` would result in `"5"`, however.

Comment: So basically the shortest repeating string is returned?

Comment: Longest repeating string, actually. `"555444555444"` would result in `"555444"`.

Comment: No, that's still shortest. the longest would be the string itself.

Comment: What 'l' for the second?

Comment: What would "AAAAAAAAAAA" return, for example?

Comment: Ugh, this is less trivial than I originally thought. This is a hackaround of a library that summarizes text, but for some reason when the input string is shorter than the desired text length, it repeats pieces of the input text over and over. I only want the pieces one time.

Comment: And the example `"xxAbcdAbcdAbcd"` will consist of just one "repitition"? Same with `"AbcdAbcdAbcdY"`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, correct.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer Do you know the conditions when it fails? Like, if you know for sure it only repeats strings length 4 or less? If so, can you simply check if the first 1/2/3/4 length strings are repeated indefinitely? (`Abcd` can be seen to repeat, but `Hell` won't as there's an `o` later)

Comment: `(\w+?)\1\+` comes pretty close to what you want, but it's not perfect.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair It fails when the input string is of insufficient complexity for it to create a summary. The examples I posed were simplifications -- the real strings would be multiple sentences of human-readable text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    private static string FindShortestRepeatingString(string value)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value", "The value paramter is null.");

        for (int substringLength = 1; substringLength <= value.Length / 2; substringLength++)
            if (IsRepeatingStringOfLength(value, substringLength))
                return value.Substring(0, substringLength);
        return value;
    }

    private static bool IsRepeatingStringOfLength(string value, int substringLength)
    {
        if (value.Length % substringLength != 0)
            return false;
        int instanceCount = value.Length / substringLength;
        for (int characterCounter = 0; characterCounter < substringLength; characterCounter++)
        {
            char currentChar = value[characterCounter];
            for (int instanceCounter = 1; instanceCounter < instanceCount; instanceCounter++)
                if (value[instanceCounter * substringLength + characterCounter] != currentChar)
                    return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This looks better than some of the other solutions (including mine) because you don't need to allocate new `string` objects while you check for suitable substrings. But maybe it depends on the size of the `value` string which solution performs best?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public string ShortestRepeating(string str)
{
    for(int len = 1; len <= str.Length/2; len++)
    {
        if (str.Length % len == 0)
        {
            sub = str.SubString(0, len);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str.Length)
            while(builder.Length < str.Length)
                builder.Append(sub);
            if(str == builder.ToString())
                return sub;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

This just starts looking at sub strings starting at the beginning and then repeats them to see if they match.  It also skips any that do not have a length that doesn't evenly divide into the original strings length and only goes up to the length / 2 since anything over that cannot be a candidate for repeating.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can work:

```
static string FindShortestSubstringPeriod(string input)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    return input;

  for (int length = 1; length <= input.Length / 2; ++length)
  {
    int remainder;
    int repetitions = Math.DivRem(input.Length, length, out remainder);        
    if (remainder != 0)
      continue;
    string candidate = input.Remove(length);
    if (String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(candidate, repetitions)) == input)
      return candidate;
  }
  return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this:

```
private static string FindRepeat(string str)
{
    var lengths = Enumerable.Range(1, str.Length - 1)
        .Where(len => str.Length % len == 0);

    foreach (int len in lengths)
    {
        bool matched = true;

        for (int index = 0; matched && index < str.Length; index += len)
        {
            for (int i = index; i < index + len; ++i)
            {
                if (str[i - index] != str[i])
                {
                    matched = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (matched)
            return str.Substring(0, len);
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
^(\w*?)\1*$
```

It captures as few characters as possible where the captured sequence (and only the captured sequence) repeat 0 or more times.  You can get the text of the shortest match from the capture afterwards, as per Jacob's answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a regular expression with back-references.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(@"^(.*?)\0*$");
String smallestRepeat = match.Groups[0];
```

Comment: This doesn't work - Given "AbcdAbcd", it gives me back a match of "AbcdAbcd".

Comment: My mistake, it needed the `?` quantifier. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Just tested it again, and it didn't make a difference.  However, by combining this with the regex I came up with above, I think I managed to get a working regex.